# Font size relative to container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-size

i am designing a site that adjusts itself to the window size, and i need to make the text size relative to it's container (a div). I searched about doing it with css, and found out that it is not possible. So i am trying with JavaScript, but i am not a JavaScript programmer. So i searched each piece of the code i needed and compiled it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        while(true) {
            document.getElementById("text").style.fontSize = $("container").height();
        }
    });
</script>
```

(the "while" is to re-size it constantly, considering that the user might re-size the window)

I put the script in the "head" tag, and it doesn't work. I don't know if the script is wrong, or if it is not running. What am i doing wrong?
Also i want to put a delay in the end of the script, to avoid it running like crazy, but i don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance,

Luca

Thanks to the answers, but nothing working.
I guess that the script is not running, what can be wrong??? Please help!

Comment: `while(true)` is an infinite loop, you should at least use `setInterval`. But then I don't see the point why you should resize it that way. Have you tried [`$(window).resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)?

Comment: Instead of running a `while (true)` loop when the document finishes loading, you probably want to just have the font resizing code run on a window resize event (since you're using jQuery, you can use their [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event binder).

Comment: `em`'s are relative to container size. What are you talking about? Give font sizes in `em`'s instead of in pixels.

Comment: You can use `font-size:[1-100]<vw/vh/vmin>;`

Comment: @Sanchit: `em` is _not_ relative to the container size.

Comment: @Sanchit `em`s are NOT relative to the container but to the parent font size. Also, `em` doesn't guarantee that the font will resize when the window is resized.

Comment: Hrm... -1 for me. I did some googling. My bad I thought it was container. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this instead (if I understand correctly what you want to do):

```
$(".container").each(function(){ //if container is a class
    $('.text', $(this)).css({'font-size': $(this).height()+"px"}); //you should only have 1 #text in your document, instead, use class
});
```

or something more like this

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.text').css({'font-size': $('#container').height()+"px"});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/AyRMC/

You can use viewport units:

```
.vw{
    font-size:3vw;
    color:red;
}
.vh{
    font-size:3vh;
    color:green;
}
.vmin{
    font-size:3vmin;
    color:blue;
}
```

Doesn't have *full* support quite yet, but IE10, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all support it.

One downside (or possible upside) is that, at least in chrome, the text doesn't scale as the viewport is resized.

Compatibility: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you are making a responsive site, then you can change the font-size based on `document.documentElement.clientWidth` inside of the window resize handler.

Also, you can use `em` units instead of pixels which are scalable and mobile-friendly.

CSS3 also has a new interesting "root em" unit :

> CSS3 introduces a few new units, including the rem unit, which stands
>   for "root em". If this hasn't put you to sleep yet, then let's look at
>   how rem works.
>
> The em unit is relative to the font-size of the parent, which causes
>   the compounding issue. The rem unit is relative to the root—or the
>   html—element. That means that we can define a single font size on the
>   html element and define all rem units to be a percentage of that.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).resize(function() {
            document.getElementById("text").style.fontSize = $(".container").height(); 
            // let container is a class 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .resize() event handler which will only fire when the window is resized

```
var constant = [Some magic number]    

$(window).resize(function() {
    var fontSize = $(this).height()*$(this).width()*constant;
    $(html).css("font-size",fontSize)
}
```

Using a constant to calculate the font size based on the new width/height

Comment: probably needs a unit appended as well, like`+'px'`